# Dynamics CRM 2011 Outlook client and browser rendering

Tags: internet-explorer, outlook, dynamics-crm-2011

So, with Dynamics CRM 2011 you can use the [Browser Client or the Outlook client](http://blogs.c5insight.com/Home/tabid/40/entryid/218/CRM-and-Outlook-6-Reasons-to-Use-CRM-for-Outlook.aspx).

They look very similar, which makes me think the Outlook Client must be using Internet Explorer (or components thereof) to render most of the pages. I've been trying to find out if that is the case, without much success. So my question is:

Does the Outlook Client for Dynamics CRM 2011 outsource the rendering of pages to Internet Explorer in some way?
If so, is it affected by the version of Internet Explorer that is installed on the PC (7,8,9 etc), or does it use a separate Trident render engine built into Outlook (and thus it would stays the same if you upgrade IE on the PC).

Edit: I'm specifically looking at Outlook 2007 if that makes a difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full page forms in Outlook are rendered by IE.  All current versions of CRM use either IE7, or IE in compatibility mode for IE8.

UR11 contains a lot of fixes for IE10 compatibility issues.

Comment: @GregOwens This is not good. This is not good at all. I'm running a solution that doesn't work in IE7/IE8. I thought any potential issues with CRM-Outlook could be resolved by upgrading the IE. This is a **major** show-stopper. Can anything be done about it?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old question but if anyone wonders - this is the message that "window.navigator.userAgent" in outlook 2010 returns:

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)